# How can I debug external code in Visual Studio 2019 when there is no PDB available?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, closedxml, pdb-files

I am trying to debug some issues occurring within an external library (ClosedXML). If I can work out exactly what's going wrong, I should be able to apply workarounds to the code that calls it.

I have added ClosedXML and manage it via NuGet.

Unfortunately, the debugger states that ClosedXML.PDB cannot be loaded. The checkboxes for 'Microsoft Symbol Servers' and 'NuGet.org Symbol Server' are both checked.

A suggestion was to generate my own pdb file. So, I cloned the ClosedXML repo, checked out the 0.95.4 commit (the version of the NuGet package I'm using) and built the project in Debug mode. I then directly referenced the pdbs produced in the ClosedXML binaries folder in the 'No Symbols Loaded' page in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, none of them work. They each have the same error message:

```
...\source\repos\ClosedXML\ClosedXML\bin\Debug\net46\ClosedXML.pdb: PDB does not match image.
...\source\repos\ClosedXML\ClosedXML\bin\Debug\net40\ClosedXML.pdb: PDB does not match image.
...\source\repos\ClosedXML\ClosedXML\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClosedXML.pdb: PDB does not match image.
```

This isn't surprising as the DLL and the PDB weren't built on the same machine, but it is unfortunate.

So, my current workaround is to dereference the NuGet package and instead reference the DLL I've built locally. This works, but it is far from ideal.

To confirm, 'Just My Code' is disabled.

Is there any way I can debug the external code without resorting to changing references each time?

Comment: Probably decompiling can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2019 once you know what's wrong in the decompiled code, it should be straight forward to fix in the original code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to investigate called methods and parameters in ClosedXML without .pdb.